# unable to use two sata drives connected

Tags: boot

I have an Asus P5KPL-CM Motherboard which doesn't support AHCI mode in BIOS only ATA/IDE Configuration . I used to create a clone disk in case of disk failure or something wrong . So I can boot from the parent or the clone disk independently but not with both connected . If two SATA hard disks are connected pc freezes in bios phase ( I can't use the command PRESS DEL TO RUN SETUP , in order to choose between two hard disks which first ...) . Shutdown and disconnect one SATA disk and everything is fine ! ! !  I should refer there is no problem if the second disk is formatted , that's why I can do a clone disk .
how could I overcome this ?

Comment: How do you know it's the BIOS that's freezing? If your disks are actually clones (identical), then Windows bootloader will become fatally confused with both connected at the same time. Some software (Macrium Reflect, for instance) will claim to "clone" disks, but actually will change the disk ID in sector 0, and, again, the Windows bootloader will not recognize the new disk and fail to boot.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem finally taking a risk . I made a hot plugging of the second sata disk and after that I viewed My Computer and Device Manager and saw nothing. At last I clicked on Disk drives and asked for hardware changes . In a few seconds the second drive appeared on Device Manager and My Computer , restarted the computer and everything is OK . Now I can press DEL to run Setup an see my two hard disks as M3 and M4 in BIOS